# Is there an expansion for element-wise scaled convolution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution

If $x = a\cdot b$ is used to indicate $x_i = a_i\cdot b_i$,
$y = a / b$ denotes $y_i = a_i / b_i$, 
and $a*b$ denotes convolution,

then is there a simplification for this expression:

$$
\frac{(a\cdot b)*(c\cdot d)}{b*d}
$$

It was tempting to assume this $=a*c$, but I couldn't find any property for it ([the Wikipedia page for convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) only shows scalar multiplication, but not anything more).

The reason is that I want to compute the expression shown, but some elements of $b$ and $d$ are very close to zero.

Thanks a lot for any advice you can provide.

Comment: I get that the $n$th term of the expression you wrote is $\left(\sum_m a_m b_m c_{n-m} d_{n-m}\right)/\left( \sum_m b_m d_{n-m} \right)$, which looks like a weighted sum expression -- it doesn't appear to simplify down.

Comment: Then do you have any thoughts as to what the $n$th term would be in the case when the denominator approaches zero? I should note that all vectors are nonnegative, so if $(b*d)_n = 0$, then at least one of all $b_i$ or $d_i$ multiplied to compute $(b*d)_n$ must be zero, meaning the numerator is also going to zero for that term. My intuition says to replace with $(a*c)_n$ when $(b*d)_n\approx 0$  (rationalizing using l'Hopital's rule). Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't think the above will simplify as there are no general rules for interchanging Hadamard products and convolution. However, I _think_ (though am not sure) you can evaluate the above as a IIR filter with an impulse as input if you let $b \ast d$ be the coefficients on the output and $(a \cdot b) \ast (c \cdot d)$ be the coefficients on the input. It might also help you understand the stability of the system to view it like this, since if either $\hat{b}$ or $\hat{d}$ equals $0$ for any $\omega$, then the denominator will be zero and the above is at best in an indeterminant form.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 I agree about the indeteriminate form you describe. Will $(a\cdot b)*(c\cdot d)_i$ approach $(a*c)_i$ when $(b*d)_i \approx 0$? I've seen this in practice (and it is certainly true when the convolution comes from an inner product of length 1), but just wanted to have a cleaner proof.

Comment: @Oliver I don't think that is true in general. Don't both the denominator _and_ the numerator have to go to zero to evaluate an indeterminant? If so, then either $a$ would have to null $b$, or $c$ would have to null $d$. In which case, you could differentiate in the frequency domain and see if maybe you can derive something useful.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 But the numerator *must* be 0 if the denominator is 0 (see post above-- since all vectors are nonnegative, a zero value $(b*d)_i$ requires all values in the product-sum must equal zero, meaning the same must be true in the numerator). The only question is whether l'Hopital's rule is valid here.